# Как правильно оформить таблицу покупок

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать `<thead>` темным верхнюю строку, а все остальное светлым.

```css
table {
width:1090px;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
font-size: 3,36 пт;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-weight: 400; 
}

th {
background: #455a64;
color:  white; 
padding: 20px 0 20px;
}
th, td {
border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;

}

td {
padding: 20px 0 20px;
background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
 <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Purchase</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Downloads</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody class="table table-striped">
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">1</th>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>

       
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
       
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">3</th>        
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">4</th>
         <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">5</th>
       <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">6</th>
         <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th scope="row">7</th>
        <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfooter>
   <th scope="row">Total:><a href="basket"></a></Sales:></th>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сделать темным что именно?

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
    width: 1090px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-weight: 400;
}

th {
    background: #455a64;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
}

th,
td {
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}

td {
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Purchase</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Downloads</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
   </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">2</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">3</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">4</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">5</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">6</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">7</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <td scope="row">Total:<a href="basket"></a></td>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задать для верхней строки класс и навесить стили на нее. или, если класс навесить нельзя, воспользуйтесь псевдоэлементом `:first-child`:

```
<style>
  tr:first-child {background-color:darkgrey;}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```